# Magento CE 1.6 compatibility with MySQL 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.6, mysql-5.6

I have ecommerce site in magento and want to upgrade mysql version from 5.4 to 5.6. I have seen lot of users are getting issues on advance search.

I want to know that apart from advance search, is there any other issues faces by the any user on stack overflow?

Comment: Upgrading Magento first isn't an option?

Comment: Just try to run magento on another machine with MySQL 5.6.
Or... try to update Magento (i hope you don't have a broken-core). Out 1.9.2.2 works fine on 5.6 (Percona).